# Can I use Silverlight in an ActiveX Control?

Tags: silverlight, activex

I would like to create an ActiveX control that uses Silverlight. Is this possible/sensible and does anyone have an sample code for this?

I am working in a legacy (non web) system that cannot directly use WPF/Silverlight controls. But the system can access ActiveX controls. The thought is that we may be able to host Silverlight in an ActiveX control, and therefore update our rather dated UI.

Answer (score 2):

Read this article.
[Silverlight COM Ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296246(VS.95).aspx)

The article indicates activeX controls in 'agcore.dll' On windows it is actually imported through 'npctrl.dll'.

you compile may have some sort of activex control wizard.

**EDIT:** With that said. It might be as easy to host IWebBrowser in an activeX control and embedd silvelight into the browser control from local storage via 'xaml'.